# Why golang ticker.Stop() does not work in tickerTest1?

Tags: go, ticker

[image: result of two testTicker]

I know the `Stop` function can not close the channel. I am just confused with the two different results of `tickerTest1` and `tickerTest2`.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "log"
)

func tickerTest1() {
    ticker := *time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    count := 0
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
        ticker.Stop()
    }()
    for range ticker.C {
        count ++
        log.Println("tickerTest1：", count)
    }
}

func tickerTest2() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    count := 0
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
        ticker.Stop()
    }()
    for range ticker.C {
        count ++
        log.Println("tickerTest2：", count)
    }
}

func main() {
    go tickerTest1()
    tickerTest2()
}
```

Comment: I think the question is why ticks continue to be sent to `ticker.C` after `ticker.Stop()` if ticker is *a pointer* to the result of `time.NewTicker(time.Second)`

Comment: Because stopping a copy is not stopping the instance. Take the Tour of Go, especially the method section and the pointer stuff.

Comment: Screen shots of text should always be avoided! Copy and paste the text instead.

Comment: I have pasted the the text. I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`tickerTest2()` works as expected, so let's examine `tickerTest1()`.

[`time.NewTicker()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker) returns a pointer value, a value of type [`*time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker). This already hints you should use it as that: as a pointer (and should not dereference it).

Yet, you dereference it by using the indirection operator:

```
ticker := *time.NewTicker(time.Second)
```

By dereferencing it,`ticker` will be of type `time.Ticker`, a non-pointer type. And its value will be a **copy** of the value pointed by the pointer that `NewTicker()` returns.

This alone wouldn't be a problem, because Go automatically takes the address of `ticker` whenever you call a method with pointer receiver on it (such as [`Ticker.Stop()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker.Stop)). But the address that is passed as the receiver will be the address of this `ticker` variable, and any method that modifies the `time.Ticker` struct will only modify this distinct copy, and not the `time.Ticker` value that is pointed by the return value of the `NewTicker()` function.

So in effect, you only stop the copy `Ticker` stored in the `ticker` variable, and not the original `Ticker` that was returned by `NewTicker()` and which is actually sending the values on the channel. That remains unstopped.