# Golang: Why i also get a message from channel after timer stop

Tags: go

**first code (abnormal):**

```
var ti time.Timer
func init() {
    ti = *time.NewTimer(3 * time.Second)
}
func main() {
    ti.Stop()
    t := <-ti.C
    fmt.Println("End", t) 
}
```

**second code (normal):**

```
var ti *time.Timer
func init() {
    ti = time.NewTimer(3 * time.Second)
}
func main() {
    ti.Stop()
    t := <-ti.C
    fmt.Println("End", t) // deadlock!
}
```

I can't understand why fistr code also get msg from timer channel after stop. I think it is abnormal because it seems to make timer lose its role.

And second code is normal ,the different is "var ti time.Timer" and "var ti *time.Timer", one is value and other is pointer.

I'm not familiar with pointer，can someone help me?

thanks!

Comment: This should answer your question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521386/why-golang-ticker-stop-does-not-work-in-tickertest1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dereferencing ticker and its value gets copied.

Here is the Stop method:

```golang
func (t *Ticker) Stop() {
    stopTimer(&t.r)
}
```

As you copied the timer, the `&t.r` points to somewhere else. That's why your timer doesn't stop.

So you should be using `*time.Ticker` not `time.Ticker`.